# Consider a net of weak order units in a Riesz space converging in order to a weak order unit. Is there a tail whose infimum is a weak order unit?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-lattices, banach-lattices

Let $X$ be an extremally disconnected (the closure of an open set is open) compact Hausdorff space, and consider the Riesz space $C^\infty(X)$ of continuous functions from $X$ to the extended real number line $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ such that the preimage of $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $X$. By the Ogasawara theorem, this is a prototypical universally complete Reisz space.

A net $(x_i)_i$ in a Reisz space converges in order to $x$ if there exists a decreasing net $(y_j)_j$ with infimum zero such that for any $j$ there is an $i_0$ with $|x_i-x|\le y_j$ for all $i\ge i_0$.

Suppose $(f_i)_i$ is a net of weak order units (positive invertible functions) in $C^\infty(X)$, that is, for every $f_i$ the set $\{x\in X\colon f_i(x)>0\}$ is dense in $X$, that converges in order to a weak order unit $f$. Is it then true that there is an $i_0$ such that $\inf_{i\ge i_0}f_i$ is a weak order unit?